# Nginx SSL configuration setup

Tags: server, configuration, nginx, ssl, certificates

I'm using **Nginx** on **Ubuntu 18.04** with **LEMP** installed, recently I renewed my SSL certs therefore I can see some files with named .

**SSL cert related files last 2 files comes with .zip**

```
private.key                  (same as old)

public.crt                   (renewed)

STAR_sellist_com.ca-bundle   (renewed)

STAR_sellist_com.crt         (renewed)
```

**My earlier nginx configuration**

```
server {
    listen     443 ssl;

    server_name dev.sellist.com;


    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/nginx/public.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/nginx/private.key;
```

this works before my certs gonna expire . and now I can see this error

```
AWS HTTP error: cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)
```

I know something intermediate certification is not setup on right place so how can I do that ? Please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case **nginx configuration** is same no need to edit

```
server {
    listen     443 ssl;

    server_name dev.sellist.com;


    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/nginx/public.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/nginx/private.key;
```

**SSL cert related files , last 2 files comes with .zip** . Concatenate last 2 files with **public.crt**

```
private.key                  (same as old) 

public.crt                   (renewed)    

STAR_sellist_com.ca-bundle   (renewed)

STAR_sellist_com.crt         (renewed)
```

**Solution** :- In order to concatenate using `cat` command.

**Note** :- This order for concatenate is must.

```
cat public.crt STAR_sellist_com.crt STAR_sellist_com.ca-bundle > public.crt
```

Answer (score 1):

`STAR_sellist_com.ca-bundle`  file is a chain bundle. In Nginx, you have to convert the chain bundle and .crt file into one file for this run command.

`cat STAR_sellist_com.ca-bundle STAR_sellist_com.crt > STAR_sellist_com.chained.crt`

after that change virtual host syntax

`ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/nginx/STAR_sellist_com.chained.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/nginx/private.key;`

I hope it helps.

Comment: No that wasn't work for me .

Comment: but I tried same as your concatenate command like this 
`cat public.crt STAR_sellist_com.crt STAR_sellist_com.ca-bundle > public.crt `
this worked for me anyways thanks for the support

Comment: @soldier, please upvote and accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the line

`ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/nginx/public.crt;`

to

`ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/nginx/STAR_sellist_com.ca-bundle;`

We should provide full chain to ssl_certificate

Comment: No that wasn't work for me but I tried same as your concatenate command like this `cat public.crt STAR_sellist_com.crt STAR_sellist_com.ca-bundle > public.crt` this worked for me anyways thanks for the support.